# Strange iPad screen issue - moving between views pushed controls up?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I am having a strange problem when I switch views using the UIView begin, set and commit animations.

For some reason when I change the views it is pushing the elements that I have on the screen up by about 10 pixels?

For example, when I load my first view the elements on the screen load correctly, but as soon as I move to another view everything (in all my views) gets pushed up 10 pixels.

The following code is my method in my AppDelegate that I call when the button is pressed. GameState is my singleton class for tracking the ViewController.

```
- (void)gotoStartUp
{
    StartUpController *myStartUp = [[StartUpController alloc] initWithNibName:@"StartUpController" bundle:nil];
    [self setStartUpController:myStartUp];
    [myStartUp release];

    GameState *myVC = [GameState currentGameState];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone forView:window cache:YES];
        //[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:window cache:YES];
    [myVC.currentViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.window addSubview:[startUpController view]];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

I then have another ViewController and View that I switch to based on the selected button using a similar method like the following:

```
- (void)gotoNewGame
{   
    NewGameController *myStartUp = [[NewGameController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewGameController" bundle:nil];
    [self setNewGameController:myStartUp];
    [myStartUp release];

    GameState *myVC = [GameState currentGameState];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone forView:window cache:YES];
        //[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:window cache:YES];
    [myVC.currentViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.window addSubview:[newGameController view]];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

I then use these methods to navigate between my views (I have 5 of them set up like this).

I've been trying to get my arms around views and view controllers and putting them all together. I finally felt like I was making some progress, but I don't have any idea where to start on this one. Keep in mind that I'm brand new to Objective-C (and development as well).

Here's what the screen looks like on the initial load (everything looks right):
[image]

Here's what the screen looks like after I've switch views and come back to the same screen:

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help!
I thought I better post my Application Delegate header file as well:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class StartUpController, FightController,PrepareArenaController, NewGameController, LoadGameController;

@interface ArenaAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    IBOutlet StartUpController *startUpController;
    IBOutlet LoadGameController *loadGameController;
    IBOutlet NewGameController *newGameController;
    IBOutlet PrepareArenaController *prepareArenaController;
    IBOutlet FightController *fightController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet StartUpController *startUpController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet LoadGameController *loadGameController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NewGameController *newGameController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet PrepareArenaController *prepareArenaController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet FightController *fightController;


- (void)gotoStartUp;
- (void)gotoGameInstructions;
- (void)gotoLoadGame;
- (void)gotoNewGame;
- (void)gotoPrepareArena;
- (void)gotoFight;

@end
```

Comment: I've had a very similar problem - the culprit seems to be the status bar. In my case, I only had one view, but it would load at first in the higher position (leaving a blue bar at the bottom of the screen when I set the window color to blue), but if I rotated it and rotated it back, it shifted downward. Would love to get a solution for this.

Comment: are you using a navigation controller and restricting orientations?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code (from [here](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/3953-title-bar-top-view.html#post165423)). It helped me

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    // to fix the controller showing under the status bar
    self.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
}
```